# Login.php returning blank

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

My login.PHP page returns blank. I have tried changing everything i can think of. I know i'm probably just missing something simple. It's supposed to return errors. Here is the code for login.PHP (I also turned on a separate error reporter to see what errors i get and i'm getting "array()"

```
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_post) === false){
    $username = $_post['username'];
    $password = $_post['password'];

    if (empty($username)=== true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password.';
    }
    else if (user_exists($username) ===false) {
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
    }
    else if (user_active($username) ===false){
        $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activate your account yet.';
    } 
}

print_r($errors);
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: may I suggest that instead of `if (empty($_post) === false)` you write `if (!empty($_POST))`, etc, it's much more readable. and capitalise `$_POST`

Comment: or just `if ($_post)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (empty($_post) === false){
$username = $_post['username'];
$password = $_post['password'];
```

should be

```
if (empty($_POST) === false){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

try adding more verbose to see where your if statements are ending up, or `var_dump($_POST)` and var_dump($errors)

Comment: any specific reason why empty($_POST) === false ? and not just !empty($_POST) ?

Comment: I prefer !empty($_POST) myself but I was just changing the least amount of code as possible :)

Comment: Wow, all i had to do it capitalize my $_POST, Thank you for the fast response. that seemed to fix everything. Thank you very much!
@GGIO no reason, that's just how i am learning i guess. I'll change it though.

Comment: make sure to take the advice from everyone with specifics to formatting and making your life easier :)

Answer (score 1):

1. use $_POST instead of $_post
2. use `$username = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : false;` and then just ask `if ($username)`
3. don't forget to sanitize input before asking DB

Answer (score 0):

Try using $_POST (all caps).

Functions are case insensitive, but variables aren't.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['...'] - allways user CAPS,

$_GET['...'] - too